# Как запустить elf файл?

Tags: linux, c, binary, elf, execute

Есть файл test.elf . Я правильно понимаю что исполняемый файл только для Linux?
Как мне в таком случае запустить эту программу?

Comment: если вы хотите запустить ее из терминала - выставить executable bit и просто указать путь к ней, например `./test.elf`

Comment: Не совсем, elf - executable and linkable format -  принят ка стандарт почти на всех юникс платформах. Но это не означает, что один и тотже экзешник можно где угодно запустить. Посмотрите - `file test.elf`.

Comment: Помимо сказанного @0xdb запусти `ldd test.elf` — тоже может пролить немного света.